# Paper-dropdown-menu does not adequately open

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

The paper-dropdown-menu (Dart Polymer Elements 1.0.0-rc.3) does not adequately open. See the image:

[image]

1. The paper-dropdown-menu closed.
2. Open the first time.
3. Open the second time.
4. Open the third time.
5. Open the fourth time.

The menu becomes smaller with each new opening.

Html code:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Selecione Produto Componente">
  <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{produtos}}" as="item_dropdown" index-as="index_iii">
      <paper-item class="produto" on-tap="selecionarProdutoComponente">{{item_dropdown.produto.descricao}}</paper-item>
    </template>
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Need I to define a specific attribute or CSS to work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same behavior in my project. When I deploy with dart2js, the behavior is correct with Chrome. I think this is a Dartium specific bug, so if nobody objects, then consider file a bug on the dart-polymer project.

Comment: Great, didn't check that. A new Dartium is work in progress anyway. This is not the only issue the outdated Chrome version causes the current Dartium is based on.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 3, 2016 using Dart 1.14.2 and Dart Polymer 1.0.0-rc.15, I still see this behavior with the dropdowns.  To fix, I had to add the "no-animations" attribute to the paper-dropdown-menu.